# C++11 rvalue references vs references vs pointers vs "normal" members

Tags: class, pointers, c++11, reference, rvalue-reference

I have code like this:

```
class A{
};

class B{
   B(A &&a) : a(std::move(a)){};
   A a;
}

A a{};
B b{ std::move(a) };
// a is unusable
```

I use rvalue, because I do not want object to be copy-ed.

I am thinking of changing the `class B` to use references:

```
class A{
};

class B{
   B(A &a) : a(a){};
   A &a;
}

A a{};
B b{ a };
// a is usable
```

Will there be any negative effects of this, except live-time concerns? I do not reassign the `a object`, so I do not need pointers. but should I consider them?

Comment: In your first example the object gets copied anyway.  You need `B(A &&a) : a(std::move(a)) {}`.

Comment: May or may not be a problem, but now code external to `B` may effectively modify `B`'s state (by way of modifying `::a`). This was not possible originally. `B` must now be prepared for the possibility of the value of `B::a` changing at any time.

Comment: another consequence is Implicitly-declared c-tors will not be generated anymore

Answer (score 1):

Why not let the caller decide whether to move or copy its `A` object?

```
class A {};

class B {
public:
    B(A a_param) : a(std::move(a_param)) {}
private:
    A a;
};

void f1() {
    A a;
    B b{a}; // Makes a copy, a is still usable.
}

void f2() {
    A a;
    B b{std::move(a)}; // Does a move, a is not usable.
}

void f3() {
    B b{A{}}; // Does a move of the temporary object.
}
```

Comment: i deleted copy constructor, objects are non-copy-able. but objects are huge anyway. question is if I move to reference-members, what should I expect?